# Django @cache_page with SITE_ID (Site Framework)

Tags: python, django, caching

I'm using Django's Site Framework to run multiple websites and each `SITE_ID` is based on current city data.

Any way to `@cache_page` so Django will cache the correct view based on `SITE_ID`?

This doesnt work as Django will return the same cached value on all websites regardless of `SITE_ID`

```
@cache_page(24 * 60 * 60)
def my_page(request):
   myview = table.objects.filter(city_id=settings.SITE_ID)
   #...
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like: [this line](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/cache.py#L13) talks about this

```
@cache_page(24*60*60, key_prefix="%s" % settings.SITE_ID) 
def my_page(request):
   myview = table.objects.filter(city_id=settings.SITE_ID)
   #...
```

or better cache the querysets which is easier to controll

```
def my_page(request):
   cities = cache.get('cities_%s' % settings.SITE_ID)
   if not cities: 
       cities = table.objects.filter(city_id=settings.SITE_ID)
       cache.set('cities_%s' % settings.SITE_ID, cities, 24*60*60)
   #...
   #...
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, the result is the same and the page is randomly returning one of the cached files. Pretty much, when I keep refreshing the page, Django is randomly swapping between the sites and showing wrong city results.

Comment: Yes, also restarted server and even renamed the view just to make sure. Any ideas?

Comment: why do you cache the whole view btw? you could cache the querysets which is the main weight of the view

Comment: The page does not change very often so caching the page view seems to be the easiest and most beneficial. Also the view has 6 queries so I thought it was the best approach. What do you suggest?

Comment: @WayBehind whatelse does your page have except for cities? at the end of the day, you dont win much by caching the whole view if your page's main content is cities. and if you cache small parts, it is easy to controll the flow. i would cache the queryset, thats what i do always.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will give it a shot. BTW the page has Top 10 results for five different niche categories for each city.